# problem with ad-hoc network simulation with different routing protocol using ns2

Tags: networking

When using DSR , interface queue type is  Queue/DropTail/PriQueue,  no. of node 50; the 
Segmentation Core dumped occured. But when using DSR, interface queue type 
is CMUPriQueue, no.of node 50, then it simulates sucessfully.
When using AODV , interface queue type is CMUPriQueue ,  no. of node 50; the 
Segmentation Core dumped occured. But when using AODV, interface queue type 
is  Queue/DropTail/PriQueue, no.of node 50, then it simulates sucessfully.

Therefore I have code my tcl script to use different interface queque:
  AODV using Queue/DropTail/PriQueue
  DSR using CMUPriQueue

Questions:
 Does any body know what is the reason for this?
 What is the difference between these two queues?

I apreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it drop the packets at that time of queue is full it not accept other packets thats called drop tail queue. CMU priqueue used to transmit the routing protocol packet at priority manner thats called the CMU priqueue